# JUnit test for S.o.println function failing even after adding \n to expected output

Tags: java, junit

I'm JUnit testing a function that prints using System.out.println(). I take the expected output + \n and compare it to what was printed, and the test fails. However, if I switch from S.o.println() to S.o.print() and don't add the newline character to the expected output it works fine. The error makes it look like maybe two newline are being added, but adding \n\n didn't work either.

The function being tested:

```
public void printTime() {
    String h0 = "";
    String m0 = "";
    String s0 = "";
    if(hour < 10)
        h0 = "0";
    if(min < 10)
        m0 = "0";
    if(sec < 10)
        s0 = "0";

    System.out.println(h0+hour+":"+m0+min+":"+s0+sec);
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void testPrintTime() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));

    clock.printTime();
    assertEquals("12:00:00\n", baos.toString());
}
```

The error

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<12:00:00[]
> but was:<12:00:00[
]
>
```

Comment: What happens if you expect `"12:00:00\r\n"`?

Comment: You can use [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/)' `SystemOutRule` for testing that code. It has a method `getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator()` which allows you to write tests that don't depend on the OS.

Answer (score 3):

If printTime does a println, autoflush will write the buffered text. This seems to be done already.

The error: Under Windows "\r\n" might be tested against.
Try `trim()` or adding `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos, true)); // Autoflush
clock.printTime();

assertEquals("12:00:00", baos.toString().trim());
```